# What is use ng new --collection command in angular

Tags: angular

What is the use of ng new --collection command in angular. How can use it in the command prompt?

if you know anyone about it let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [angular documentation](https://angular.io/cli/new) it is used to specify -

> A collection of schematics to use in generating the initial app.

You can refer to [this documentation](https://angular.io/guide/schematics) for details of schematics.

Just the first line from the above doc -

> A schematic is a template-based code generator that supports complex
>   logic. It is a set of instructions for transforming a software project
>   by generating or modifying code. Schematics are packaged into
>   collections and installed with npm.

Comment: what do you mean real-time?